# Circular appearance of the View

Tags: android, android-animation

Is is possible to accomplish something like this in pre-L Android?

[image]

Thank you!

Comment: yes, ofcourse it is!

Comment: @Blackbelt, can you recommend me what to use :)

Answer (score 0):

I use this library for some animation effects
https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidViewAnimations
maybe can help you